# A for-comprehrension with mixed types and WS calls

Tags: scala

How do I do a for comprehension (or flatmaps) that mixes futures and non-futures to return a Future list of results? An example:

```
  private def fetchWSResponseBodies(futureSetLongs: Future[Set[Long]]): Future[List[String]] = {
    for {
      setLongs: Set[Long] <- futureSetLongs
      long: Long <- setLongs // Mulitple longs
      wsRespone: Future[WSResponse] <- ws.url(s"someURL/$long").get
    } yield {
      wsRespone.body
    }
  }
```

I'm having difficult figuring out how to extrapolate this logic into non-blocking code using flatmaps/maps or anything else. Help appreciated!

Comment: To get from `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]` use `Future.sequence(/*for-comp*/)`.

Comment: What is WS? Do you get a compilation error from the code you have here?

Comment: I think WS is the Play WS API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should compile, but doesn't do any error handling:

```scala
private def fetchWSResponseBodies(futureSetLongs: Future[Set[Long]]):
    Future[List[String]] =
  futureSetLongs.flatMap { ids =>
    Future.sequence(ids.map { id =>
      ws.url(s"someURL/$id").get().map(_.body)
    }.toList)
  }
```